# Multiple threads calling same method in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, static

I have the following C# code snippet in which I have simulated my problem. In this program I have a Service function that call ReadRooms method.
Now I am calling the service method on different threads. I was expecting  that both ServiceCall and ReadRooms method will fired equally but I am getting below result that is not correct.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void ReadRooms(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reading Room::" + i);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
        public static void CallService(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ServiceCall::" + i);
            ReadRooms(i);

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread[] ts = new Thread[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                ts[i] = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        int temp = i;
                        CallService(temp);


                    });
                ts[i].Start();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                ts[i].Join();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("done");
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` to the methods you are calling.  similar to the `synchronized`  keyword in java

Comment: @sircapsalot:I tried this but still I am getting wrong result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are still 'capturing the loop variable'. You are creating a `temp` but too late, when `i` is already captured.

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   int temp = i;              // outside the lambda
   ts[i] = new Thread(() =>
   {
        //int temp = i;       // not here
        CallService(temp);
   });
   ts[i].Start();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your thread action is closing over the variable `i` instead of its current value. You therefore have a race between the thread reading `i` and the increment in the for loop. You can pass it as a parameter instead:

```
ts[i] = new Thread(index =>
{
    CallService((int)index);
});
ts[i].Start(i);
```

alternatively you can move the copy of `temp` to inside the loop instead of the thread action:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int temp = i;
    ts[i] = new Thread(() =>
    {
        CallService(temp);
    });
    ts[i].Start();
}
```

Comment: There is no race for `i`

Comment: @HenkHolterman - If `i` is incremented before the thread reads the value, then different threads can see the same value. How is that not a race?

Comment: It's not what we normally call a race because `i` was not intended to be shared in the first place. It's kind of true but not the core problem. And it's not something you can fix with `lock`.

Answer (score 3):

You should put this line

```
int temp = i;
```

before the Thread creation

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int temp = i;
    ts[i] = new Thread(() => CallService(temp));
    ts[i].Start();
}
```

This way you will create a local copy of i that will be used by the lambda expression.