# Multithread in C#: line of code never reached

Tags: c#, multithreading

My situation is slightly different from [multiple threads calling same method in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409547/multiple-threads-calling-same-method-in-c-sharp). I have a same function called by several threads, this function read different files in different threads. Within this function there is another method called by all threads. But none of the threads ever finish reading the files so the last Console.WriteLine() is never called.

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[numThreads];
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
    int temp = i;
    threads[i] = new Thread(() => readFiles(temp));                    
    threads[i].Start();
}

public void readFiles(int threadId) {
    // this is called
    Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} starting...", threadId);
    string line = "";
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(tempFolder + threadId + ".txt");
    int cnt = 0;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //dosmething(line);
        cnt++;
    }

    // this is never reached, no matter whether I comment out dosomething() or not
    Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} total {1} lines...", threadId, cnt);
    sr.Close();
}
```

Comment: I would put a print inside the loop and see if that is printing continuously or not at all.

Comment: This is not a complete program. You left out essential parts, such as where you wait for the worker threads to finish executing.

Comment: Show the complete Main() method that calls this. Most likely it stops before the threads are done.

Comment: So, does the While block get infinite recursion or does the readFiles method get exited earlier than expected?

Comment: Using threads for File I/O is usually counterproductive. Did you measure anything?

Comment: Might those threads be encountering a thrown exception (such as an IO error on the `StreamReader`)?

Comment: @Novelocrat, I don't see any exception thrown

Comment: @Chris, yes, the program calls .Join() to wait

Comment: @HenkHolterman, could you elaborate why this is counterproductive?

Comment: @Yang Your hard drive can only access one location on disk at a time.  it's just going to synchronize your parallel requests in the best case, and in the worse case alternate between the two, resulting in dramatically *slower* performance.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is: either there is an error when reading the files (e.g. wrong path, file didn't exist, etc.) that caused the threads to terminate (thus does not execute all the lines), or (less likely) there is an infinite loop.

Try this:

```
for(;;){
    foreach(var t in threads) Console.WriteLine(t.IsAlive);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

See what it comes out?

Also note that, you did not check whether the threads terminate gracefully or throw an exception in your code. You should not just spawn threads and ask them to do something without caring whether the job is done. This the reason why, the `Task<>` class exists in .NET. It simplifies much of the heavy lifting of managing threads manually.