# Threading in C# issue

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a piece of code that runs one method and then runs the same method again with different parameters. The method takes about 45 seconds to complete so about a minute and a half in total. It looks like:

```
//start
DbInfoPackage migratedData = runfirstqueries(connectSQLServer, log);
DbInfoPackage nonMigratedData = runfirstqueries(connectOracle, log);
//end
```

Is it possible to run the methods at the same time using threading?

Comment: um.... yes? have you tried it? note: if you are running it twice *on the same server* it could be problematic, but since one is SQL-Server and one is Oracle, that probably isn't a problem.

Comment: [multiple threads calling same method in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409547/multiple-threads-calling-same-method-in-c-sharp)??

Comment: @MarcGravell Its not using the same servers. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just since people are giving much lower-level answers, using `System.Threading.Thread` and whatnot, this is what I'd do:

```
Task<DbInfoPackage> migratedDataTask = Task.Run<DbInfoPackage>(() => runfirstqueries(connectSQLServer, log));
Task<DbInfoPackage> nonMigratedDataTask = Task.Run<DbInfoPackage>(() => runfirstqueries(connectOracle, log));

Task.WaitAll(migratedDataTask, nonMigratedDataTask);

var migratedData = migratedDataTask.Result;
var nonMigratedData = nonMigratedDataTask.Result;
```

That'll run them in two concurrent tasks, wait for them both to finish, and grab the results. You'll want to add in some error handling, but that's easy enough.

If you can work it into your workflow (and hopefully you can), it's much better to use `await Task.WhenAll(migratedDataTask, nonMigratedDataTask)` instead of `WaitAll`, but I used the latter in this example to sustain your thread-blocking behavior.

Comment: Adding error handling is **not** that easy, especially when you don't _await_ tasks but call `Task.WaitAll`...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to run two methods at the same time using multithreading.

In case you want to know *how*, look into…

- …the static [`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct.aspx):

  ```
  //using System.Threading;
  DbInfoPackage migratedData = null;
  DbInfoPackage nonMigratedData = null;
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => { migratedData = …; });
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => { nonMigratedData = …; });
  ```

  It's going to be a little work figuring out when both work items have completed. If you're targeting at least version 4 of the .NET Framework, you can make life simpler with…
- …the higher-level [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx):

  ```
  //using System.Threading.Tasks;
  DbInfoPackage migratedData = null;
  DbInfoPackage nonMigratedData = null;
  Task firstTask = Task.Run(() => { migratedData = …; });
  Task secondTask = Task.Run(() => { nonMigratedData = …; });
  …
  Task.WaitAll(firstTask, secondTask);
  ```

  (I'm not very knowledgeable about the TPL, so this code example might not be optimal.)
- The new language keywords `async/await` build on top of the TPL and make the code even nicer to read. (I have no example ready for that, as I'm not usually working with the .NET Framework 4.5 / Visual Studio 2012.)

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading in `C#` can be done as desribed in this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx); e.g. with the class `Thread` as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Thread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). However it is not clear from your code whether multithreading can actually remove the performance bottleneck.