# Threading in XMLSerializer

Tags: c#, multithreading, xmlserializer

How is it possible to extend the following code to be executed in a seperate thread?

The methods calling save/load:

```
    private void Save()
    {
        ClassDiagram diagram = new ClassDiagram();
        diagram.ClassDatas = ClassDatas.ToList();
        diagram.Connectors = Connectors.ToList();

        String filePathAndName = GetSaveFilePathAndName();
        saveLoadSerialization.Save(filePathAndName, diagram);
    }

    private void Open()
    {
        String filePathAndName = GetOpenFilePathAndName();

        ClassDiagram diagram = saveLoadSerialization.Load<ClassDiagram>(filePathAndName);
        ClassDatas = new ObservableCollection<ClassData>(diagram.ClassDatas);
        Connectors = new ObservableCollection<Connector>(diagram.Connectors);
        Connectors.ToList().ForEach(c => { c.From = ClassDatas.Single(cd => cd.Number == c.FromID); c.To = ClassDatas.Single(cd => cd.Number == c.ToID); });

        RaisePropertyChanged("ClassDatas");
        RaisePropertyChanged("Connectors");
    }
```

The Save/Load XMLSerializer code looks like this - is the best approach an asynchronous thread?

```
    public void Save<T>(String filePathAndName, T data)
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream file = File.Create(filePathAndName))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                serializer.Serialize(file, data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    public T Load<T>(string filePathAndName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(filePathAndName))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(file);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        return default(T);
    }
```

Comment: how come you can't just create a lambda that creates the new thread and within that Call your Method ? here is an additional way of looking at it within a for loop as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409547/multiple-threads-calling-same-method-in-c-sharp

Comment: @DJKRAZE I have experimented with link you submitted, but I receive a error in VS.      `Thread thread = new Thread(); <-- fails here
            thread = new Thread(() => 
            {
                saveLoadSerialization.Save(filePathAndName, diagram);
            });
            thread.Start();`

Comment: Sorry about the format of the code - have some issues..

Comment: @MikaelKP `but I receive a error in VS.`. Shh, tell your exception/error message to no one. it is secret :)

Comment: @L.B Yes it is indeed a secret ;) The error is: 'System.Threading.Thread' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments